# my php codes are not showing on browser when i run a code

Tags: php

I am new in php and l set up WAMP it seems green and i created a new allies and on url it goes to phpinfo page fine but unfortunatelly my php codes not running when l hit.

I tried uninstall  Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64  then installed Wampserver 3.0.6 32 bit x86  and still not working my computer is compete-able with the both.

one thing caught my attention l can not see php or mysql on services(Local)

I will be appreciate for your help

Thanks,
Emrah

Comment: one more thing forgot to mention l removed Wampserver 3.0.6 64 bit x64 then set up the another version

Comment: All PHP scripts or one particular one? Try making a file with just `<?php echo 'hello Emrah, I work :)';`

Comment: What do you mean by "codes are not showing on browser"?  You're not *supposed* to see the PHP code in the browser.  What's the actual problem here?

Comment: Not exactly sure how Wamp works, but it sounds like apache is not recognizing php. .. if you're planning on becoming a serious developer, I recommend changing your environment to Linux. You can do this by using VMware, installing Ubuntu, and running your stack there. There are multiple tutorials for this. Wamp is ok but won't mold you the right way.

Comment: Are you opening your file via the http:/ /localhost URL or file://path/to/file ?. You need to access it via localhost for Apache and php to process it.

Comment: hi guys Thanks for your answers but l dont think the issue what you suggest just one more thing l realized l can not access to my phpMyAdmin

Comment: hi guys Thanks for your answers but l dont think the issue what you suggest just one more thing l realized l can not access to my phpMyAdmin   do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: @David l sorted my host problem and when l execute the code it will come up like <html>
<body>
<p> Hello World </p>
hello Emrah, I work :)

</body>
</html>

Comment: @David l sorted my host problem and when l execute the code it come up like { <html>
<body>
<p> Hello World </p>
hello Emrah, I work :) (this is suppose to be php)

</body>
</html>} also do l have to add my files to execute them all time ? and is any way to set on the text editor to run the code (l am using Notepad ++) ...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP code should not showup on a webpage, that is because PHP works from the server and not from the browser like HTML and CSS. Try to make the following file index.php and place the following code in it:

```
<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
```

now open your browser and go to: localhost/index.php. You should see Hello World

Comment: Hi wes thanks for your reply can you clear that for me please : Do l need to add a file like (<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>) to some places in apache server or even l put the file on the desktop  and try to run, will it execute it, like java script or do l need to save the php file in server and if so where about in server ? thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Hello Emrullah, you have to put the file index.php in your htdocs directory of apache. That is the same place where you put the HTML files.

Comment: Thanks @wes for your reply , sorry but i am new in php and it is my first time to set up server after big straggling anyway could you please let me know where can get index.php file ? l tried to find in apache but they are simple html ones .... Thanks

Comment: I must have mid understood you, you need to create index.php . not to sound horrible but I would recommend to watch a tutorial on YouTube or go to w3schools.